# Can you help me understand packed binary data in python

Tags: python

I followed an example to convert 24bit audio to bytes.

For example:

```
struct.pack('<i', 4000000)
```

Gives:

```
b'\x00\t=\x00'
```

Can you help me understand the packed binary data

> \x00\t=\x00

How do we interpret it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the byte representation for 4000000 using this:

```
In [14]: x = 4000000                                                                                                                                                                

In [15]: print("%08X" % x)                                                                                                                                                          
003D0900
```

But on x86 and x64 machines, integers are stored LSB first, so the bytes in memory will be

```
00 09 3D 00
```

Those translate to the following characters:

```
In [46]: print(b"%c%c%c%c" % (0x00, 0x09, 0x3D, 0x00))
b'\x00\t=\x00'
```

So `0x09` is `\t` and `0x3D` is `=`.

We can recreate the original value using `ord`, some bit shifts, and addition:

```
In [52]: (ord('=') << 16) + (ord('\t') << 8)
Out[52]: 4000000
```

In the comments, you asked "why it isn't just \t=". Hopefully this example answers that question:

```
In [8]: struct.unpack('<i', b'\t=')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c3b2a260fbdf> in <module>
----> 1 struct.unpack('<i', b'\t=')

error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

The `'<i'` tells `pack` and `unpack` that they are working with 4-byte little-endian integers, so we need to give them at least 4 bytes.

You also asked "why not \x00\t\x00=\x00". This time we promise 4 bytes but deliver 5:

```
In [10]: struct.unpack('<i', b'\x00\t\x00=\x00')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-8f3448548a2a> in <module>
----> 1 struct.unpack('<i', b'\x00\t\x00=\x00')

error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

Maybe I confused you by leaving out the `0x00` bytes in the reassembly:

```
In [11]: (0 << 24) + (ord('=') << 16) + (ord('\t') << 8) + 0                                                                                                                        
Out[11]: 4000000
```

Comment: so may I ask why it isn't just \t= but \x00\t=\x00? or why not \x00\t\x00=\x00

Comment: Excellent answer. Very clean and helped me understand. Thank you every so much